# Can I get a heatsink to work without thermal paste, temporarily?

Tags: cpu, troubleshooting, heatsink, thermal-paste

Believing my motherboard to be faulty, I removed the CPU and I cleaned the thermal paste off. Now it turns out that it's the PC-speaker that is faulty. I'd like to put the CPU back in its place, somehow connect it with the heatsink, test if other ideas like changing the ram can make the PC start. But if they don't, then I'd need to remove the paste again and to put some new paste there once I get a new motherboard.

Just the fact that I'm going over my initial budget because I have to buy new paste is making me nervous. Having to use new paste every time while I make blind tests to understand what is going on feels like adding insult to injury.

Is there anything I can use that's easier to remove and commonly available in a house, instead of thermal paste (of course without risking to ruin components, including overheating the CPU)?

In case you were asking, no, I have no idea what I'm doing and I think I'm going to end up giving it to a repair shop and spend more than I would have spent by asking them to provide and mount me the parts to start with, which is infuriating.

Comment: https://www.powerelectronicsnews.com/problems-solutions/household-substitutes-for-cpu-thermal-paste , how long are you planning to test each run? I have tested computers without paste before (laptop I did not care that much about that is) and had no problems, since I started and shut down the computer pretty fast each run, as I was only testing for picture. The CPU probably does not shut down the computer before it reaches 100 degrees Celsius, which is hard to hit when only booting and shutting down. You can re-paste your CPU many times with one tube of thermal paste.

Comment: Expanding on what Anders said, Even a little (~5 gram) tube is good for at least 4 or 5 reapplications. You can get even bigger tubes of some brands (e.g. 20g of Arctic MX-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are claims that the CPU can do modest work without thermal paste and you may read
about it in the post
[Can I run my PC without Thermal Paste?](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/292749-28-thermal-paste)

However, I'm not going to go along with this post, since what happens depends a lot
on the CPU involved, the kind of work it's asked to do, and how good is its contact
of metal-on-metal (more efficient than thermal paste but not enough).

Here are some pictures taken from a
[Tom's Hardware video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxNUK3U73SI)
of what happens almost immediately in such a case,
that may convince you to wait for the paste.

AMD Athlon 1400, Temperature 370 C / 698 F, Application crashes, CPU board up in
smoke
[image]

AMD Palomino 1200, Temperature 298 C / 568 F, Application crashes, Thermal diode fails, CPU up in smoke

[image]

Comment: The video / photos are from a situation of NO HEATSINK rather than no thermal paste and hence is a very misleading answer. There is a massive amount of oppnion on this matter with 0 actual data being pointed to - which is very easy to conduct actually. My guess is without thermal paste you'd see an increase of 5-20C. Modern cpus would very likely just throttle heavily preventing permanent damage as well.

Answer (score 2):

> Just the fact that I'm going over my initial budget because I have to
>   buy new paste is making me nervous. Having to use new paste every time
>   while I make blind tests to understand what is going on feels like
>   adding insult to injury.

You don't have to clean the paste off, each time you remove the CPU, a new application only verifies its an acceptable coverage.

> Is there anything I can use that's easier to remove and commonly
>   available in a house, instead of thermal paste (of course without
>   risking to ruin components, including overheating the CPU)?

Only if you want to damage your CPU.

> In case you were asking, no, I have no idea what I'm doing and I think
>   I'm going to end up giving it to a repair shop and spend more than I
>   would have spent by asking them to provide and mount me the parts to
>   start with, which is infuriating.

Installing a CPU isn't difficult.  You should save your money and purchase more thermal paste instead of taking it to a repair shop, who by the way, will still charge you for thermal paste (at a premium price).

> I'd like to put the CPU back in its place, somehow connect it with the
>   heatsink, test if other ideas like changing the ram can make the PC
>   start.

You should not have to remove the CPU, in order to change your memory, so your reasons for attempting to run without thermal paste is without logic.  Without thermal paste, your system will overheat, within a few seconds.

Comment: I meant that I was gouing to reinstall my motherboard, paste the CPU, try the new RAM and if it doesn't work I need to remove the CPU, send back my motherboard, paste it again... and who knows if this time everything goes right?

Comment: Also, last time I revoved the heatsink I pulled out the CPU with it. I've come to see this as a risky situation, even if now I know I have to twist before pulling.

Comment: Whatever you mean, doesn't change my answer, your CPU will overheat without thermal paste.  You could always just return the motherboard and get a replacement, but without thermal paste, your CPU will overheat almost instantly.  **If that happens it will not be under warranty.  Likewise, if the pins on your motherboard socket are bent, that damage is also not under warranty.**